# vite: Rollup failed to resolve import from external directory

Tags: vue.js, vite

I have the following folder structure:

```
my-app/
├─ client/
│  ├─ src/
│  │  ├─ views/
│  │  │  ├─ *.vue
│  │  ├─ router/
│  │  │  ├─ router.js
│  │  ├─ index.html
│  │  ├─ main.js
│  │  ├─ vite.config.js
├─ specific/
│  ├─ views/
│  │  ├─ test.vue
```

*router.js* imports test.vue as follows:

`component: () => import("@specific/views/test.vue")`

But when building I get:

`[vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "vue-router" from "../specific/views/test.vue".`

*vite.config.js* contains:

```
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from "vite";

import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";

export default ({ mode }) =\> {
const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd());

    const commonPath = env.VITE_COMMON_PATH ?? "/usr/local/my-app";
    const specificPath = env.VITE_SPECIFIC_PATH ?? "/usr/local/my-app/specific";
    const outDir = env.VITE_OUTDIR ?? "/var/www/";
    
    return defineConfig({
        build: {
            outDir: `${outDir}/site/`,
            sourcemap: false,
        },
        publicDir: false,
        resolve: {
            alias: [
                { find: "vue", replacement: "vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js" },
                { find: "@", replacement: `${commonPath}/client/src` },
                { find: "@node_modules", replacement: `${commonPath}/client/node_modules` },
                { find: "@specific", replacement: specificPath },
            ],
            preserveSymlinks: true,
        },
    });

};
```

How should *rollupOptions* in *vite.config.js* be specified to get it work?

Tried to specify different inputs in rollupOptions with no success.

Also tried to add in *vite.config.js*:

`const expression = new RegExp("\specific\/views\/.*\.vue");`

and

```
rollupOptions: {
    external: [
        expression,
],
```

then it builds, but no asset for *test.vue* is added in the output folder.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by updating imports in test.vue from:

```
import { useRoute } from "vue-router";
```

to:

```
import { useRoute } from "@node_modules/vue-router";
```